# Inheriting components in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

Is it OK to inherit @Component classes in Angular 2+ ? Something like this (note that the constructors will inject a service):

```
@Component({})
export class Parent {
    constructor ( s0: Service1 ) {}
}

@Component({
     template: 'text1'
})
export class Child1 extends Parent {
    constructor ( s1: Service1 ) { super(s1); }
}

@Component({
     template: 'text2'
})
export class Child2 extends Parent {
    constructor ( s2: Service1 ) { super(s2); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure although you might want to mark type `Parent` as `abstract` and remove `@Component` as the decorator on that type as well.

```
export abstract class Parent {
    constructor (protected s0: Service1 ) {}
}
```

*I also marked `s0` as protected so it is accessible in derived types*